# Google Authentication in Expo managed app fails in production build

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-oauth, expo-auth-session

Requirement: Get the id_token from Google Auth, which is used with firebase authentication.

I'm using Expo 47.

The authentication works fine on iOS. But it fails on Android devices.

Code used:

```
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

export default function GoogleAuth() {

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: "",
    iosClientId: "",
    clientId: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!response) return;
    if (response?.params?.id_token) {
      // log in with firebase
    } else {
      console.log(response) // this logs: {"type":"dismiss"} in android APK
    }
  }, [response]);

  if (!request) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Button
      onPress={() => promptAsync({ useProxy: isDev, showInRecents: true })}
      title={"Continue with Google"}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried using `useAuthRequest` with `responseType: 'id_token'` but it says the response type is invalid. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The `schema` of `app.json` cannot have any uppercase letters. My `packageName` and `schema` was in the form of `com.myapp.mobileApp`. The login worked fine when I changed them to `com.myapp.mobileapp`.

Update: This won't work in Expo Go. You'll need to set up a Custom Dev Client to get this work: https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8

Comment: Have you changed anything in the code? I did everything you said (using the same implementation, having the same schema and package set in app.config.json) and it's still redirecting me to google page instead to my application and I get response of type dismiss.. It works on iOS, however I have the same issue on Android. Could I know what version of expo-web-browser, expo-crypto and expo-auth-session you use? I ran out of all options.

Comment: [Piotr Sobuś](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11641623/piotr-sobu%c5%9b) Can you provide the code?

Comment: We have checked on a real device and it works, apparently it does not work on the simulator. Thanks anyways!

Comment: For development, you can use a custom dev client instead of Expo Go: https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8

Comment: For me signin is working for the development, but when i export to apk and trying login its showing the account but when we select its redirect me to google.com